# Angular 7, and Spring Boot App - No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, cors, allowed-origin

I have added `@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")` annotation at the class level to my controller in the Spring Boot app, and I am still getting this error when I make an HTTP GET request from Angular to the Spring Boot app (listening on port 9000). Here is the error I get from Chrome.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:9000/employee/all' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: If you change to just CrossOrigin() do you still get the error?

Comment: Yup, thank you Alexander. it works now.

Answer (score 2):

I've found `@CrossOrigin` to be extremely finicky. You can try using just `@CrossOrigin` without any parameters as [Alexander](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5059657/alexander-staroselsky) suggested.

You can also try adding a custom `CorsFilter` Bean to the class where you call `SpringApplication.run()`. That way you've essentially got full control over the filter and can add/remove methods if necessary.

Something like this:

```
@Bean
public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
    final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();

    final CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
    config.setAllowCredentials(true);
    config.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList("*"));
    config.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Origin", "Content-Type", "Accept"));
    config.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));

    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
    return new CorsFilter(source);
}
```